# How to write strings in different row and columns in a CSV (Python)

Tags: python, string, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap some datas from a website, I can actually get them but they're written in 2 different strings looking like that in my .csv:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

and the other:

```
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

I'd like to write them following this format:

```
aaa | xxx
bbb | yyy
ccc | zzz
```

Here is the code I wrote so far :

```
# import libraries
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv  
i =0

# specify the url 
quote_page = 'http://www.alertepollens.org/gardens/garden/1/state/'

# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
response = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

# parse the html using beautiful soap and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
test = soup
with open('allergene.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    pollene = (("".join(soup.strings)[65:]).encode('utf-8')).replace(' ','').replace('\n',' ').replace('    ',' ').replace('    ',' ').replace(' ','\n')
    print pollene

    state = (([img['alt'] for img in soup.find_all('img', alt=True)])).
    print state.encode
    polen = ''.join(pollene)
    for item in state:
        writer.writerow([item])
    for item2 in pollene:
        writer.writerow([item2])
```

One of the main problem is that I have french characters (é, ù, à, etc) and using "strip()" doesn't show these characters correctly.

Do you have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Please show the code that produces these CSV outputs. Otherwise, it's not obvious how to help..

Comment: @alecxe: Just added it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
with open('a.csv') as a, open('x.csv') as x, open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
    a_lines = [line.strip()for line in a]
    x_lines = [line.strip()for line in x]
    rows = zip(a_lines, x_lines)
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

out:

```
aaa|xxx
bbb|yyy
ccc|zzz
```

`a.csv` is your first csv file, `x.csv` is your second csv file, `out.csv` is the output file.

Comment: I think I wasn't as clear as I thought :/ 

the | mean in another cell / colomn
I've a file with in one cell (and only one cell)
    aaa
    bbb
and in another one : 
    xxx
    yyy

Instead I'd like to write it like this: 
(first row) aaa (second colomn) xxx
(new row) bbb (second colomn) yyy

Don't know if it's clear, if not I can edit my question :)
my bad :/